# Creating a Map Outside of ArcGIS Environment in Python

Tags: arcpy, layouts

How would you create a batch of maps in Python from shapefiles that the user specifies and implement features (preferably user specified) used in 'Layout' view in ArcGIS such as adding legends, titles, setting map extents, etc. Once these maps are created I have a script that converts .mxd's to GIFs and animates the GIFs.

Answer (score 1):

The Mapping module of ArcPy (arcpy.mapping) is what you will need to use so I recommend that you become familiar with its [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000032000000):

> Arcpy.mapping is a Python scripting module that is part of the ArcPy
>   site package. It gets installed with ArcGIS for Desktop and is
>   available to all licenses. It was designed primarily to manipulate the
>   contents of existing map documents (.mxd) and layer files (.lyr). It
>   also provides functions to automate exporting and printing.
>   Arcpy.mapping can be used to automate map production; it extends the
>   capabilities of Data Driven Pages and is required to build complete
>   map books because it includes functions to export to, create, and
>   manage PDF documents. Finally, arcpy.mapping scripts can be published
>   as geoprocessing services and the script functionality can be made
>   available to web applications.